# Build a dropdown with an eventHandler. How to structure hooks + eventhandler

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a simple dropdown with react and functional components. On strange behavior, I've run into is the way we have to think about conjures and state. This is a simplified version of my component:

```
export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const selectElement = useRef(null);

  const handleToggle = (e) => {
    if (selectElement) {
      if (!selectElement.current.contains(e.target)) {
        setShow(!show);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleToggle, false);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("click", handleToggle, false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={selectElement} className="comp">
        <h1 onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>Select</h1>
        {show && (
          <div>
            <div>Inner 1</div>
            <div>Inner 2</div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This component behaves wrong and it's not possible to toggle the dropdown correctly. The effect handler is registered on the first render and encloses the state of the first render (if I'm not wrong here). The registered function will not receive state updates. This is causing the error.

**I'm not really sure what's the best way to fix this.** Currently, I decided to simply remove the dependency array from the `useEffect` hook so that the effect handler is created and destroyed on every render/cleanup.

I've also created a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-cookies-lpu3q?file=/src/App.js:84-1036) so my issue becomes more tangible.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will help you to solve your problem.

```
export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const selectElement = useRef(null);

  const handleToggle = (e) => {
    if (selectElement) {
      if (!selectElement.current.contains(e.target)) {
        setShow(false);
        document.removeEventListener("click", handleToggle, false);
      }
    }
  };
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setShow(true)
    document.addEventListener("click", handleToggle, false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={selectElement} className="comp">
        <h1 onClick={handleClick}>Select</h1>
        {show && (
          <div>
            <div>Inner 1</div>
            <div>Inner 2</div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. One of my tests shows that this tries to perform an update on an unmounted component. I don't see this when running the app in the browser (works fine). However, I think this is also a "dirty" implementation since you will also just store an out of date version of `handleToggle` as a clojure. In my opinion, this is also somewhat of a memory leak.